# React setState not updating on GET request, works sometimes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, state

Hi I am trying to create multiple stock ticker cards in create-react-app. The component structure is as follows:

```
  <LandingPage> 
         <Stock tick="GE">
         <Stock tick="AMD">
         <Stock tick="TSLA">
    </LandingPage>
```

Right now I am making a axios GET call to a stock API. I would like to add the response from the GET call to the state so I can retrieve throughout the component.

The Stock component set up right now is:

```
const Stocks = ({ tick }) => {
  const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_POLYGON_KEY;

  const [color, setColor] = useState("white");
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
  const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState("1");

  const [prevData, setPrevData] = useState(null);

  const previousCloseData = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await axios.get(
        `https://api.polygon.io/v2/aggs/ticker/${tick}/prev?unadjusted=true&apiKey=${apiKey}`
      );
      setLoading(false);
      if (res) {
        setPrevData(res);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setMessage(error);
    }
  };


useEffect(() => {
    previousCloseData();
    console.log(prevData);
  }, []);

return ()
export default Stocks
```

The response I get back from the API looks like:

```
{
 "ticker": "AAPL",
 "status": "OK",
 "queryCount": 1,
 "resultsCount": 1,
 "adjusted": true,
 "results": [
  {
   "T": "AAPL",
   "v": 131704427,
   "vw": 116.3058,
   "o": 115.55,
   "c": 115.97,
   "h": 117.59,
   "l": 114.13,
   "t": 1605042000000
  }
 ],
 "request_id": "6a7e466379af0a71039d60cc78e72282"
}
```

**My question is how come setPrevData(res) is not working?** Sometimes it does when I do random refreshes. If I add any dependencies to useEffect, the axios GET call happens in an infinite loop. I simply just want to store the response in a state. However, no matter what I try I just get null back. I would like to avoid using Redux or Context because this is the only API request I am making. Any help or info will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

*To clarify the console.log(prevData) returns null in the useEffect as well.

Comment: Initial `prevState` value is `null` and you only console log it when the component mounts, so it will always be `null`. What are you really trying to do? What use-case are you attempting to solve for? What and how are you verifying that the `setPrevData(res)` state update isn't working?

Comment: Do console.log above this code 
Console.log(res);
if (res) {
        setPrevData(res);
 }
and check the response coming or not

Comment: Drew Reese, thank you. I realized I was console.logging from the wrong area. The code was actually working as intended, but I was logging it on mount. Thank you for helping me debug this silly mistake. SOLVED!